# no inserta dato en mi base de datos php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

El código que tengo a continuación no me funciona, no inserta la palabra hola en la tabla Compras, he probado a hacer la sentencia sql en la consola de phpMyAdmin y funciona, la palabra hola se inserta correctamente, eso me descarta un error al configurar la columna donde se guarda. La conexión con el servidor esta bien hecha porque la utilizo en otras páginas, el problema lo tengo al insertar en la tabla Compras des de una pagina php, si inserto en la tabla principal que cree no hay problema. Cúal puede ser el error que no me deja insertar datos des de php pero si des de la consola phpmyadmin.

Este es el código que estoy probando:

```
<?php

$host_db = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
 $user_db = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
 $pass_db = "xxxxxxxxxx";
 $db_name = "xxxxxxxxxxxx";

$conexion = new mysqli($host_db, $user_db, $pass_db, $db_name);

$query = "INSERT INTO Compras (SAVED_PAYER_REF) VALUES ('hola')";

$resultc=$conexion->query($query);

 mysqli_close($conexion);

?>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Un dato tal vez relevante es que la página no se abre en el navegador sino que es una pagina donde un servidor me envia variables por POST no se si influencia a la hora de establecer la conexion con el servidor.

Comment: No te arroja un error especifico ?? revisaste los logs ¿? Mutesra la tabla Compras a ver como es.

Comment: en el log me sale solo esto GET /php/js/menu.js HTTP, que no se porque dado que en mi carpeta php no tengo ningun js

Comment: ¿Seguro que está entrando en ese archivo? Pon algo como `echo 'hola';` para verificar. Si se muestra la cadena, entonces verifica la conexión y controla errores, por ejemplo el INSERT puede fallar por clave duplicada o por error de sintaxis.

Comment: si yo ejecuto la pagina no me da ningun error el problema es cuando el banco la ejecuta y me pasa las variables que algo falla

Comment: ¿Qué URL tienes configurada en la retrollamada del banco (callback)? Dices que si la ejecutas tú no te da ningún problema, ¿pero te inserta el registro como se espera? Según parece, por el registro de acceso, la retrollamada no está bien configurada, de ahí que no se ejecute tu PHP.

Comment: Voto cierre de la pregunta por tratarse de una problema que no puede reproducirse. El origen del mal funcionamiento parece estar en algún punto del procedimiento de la pasarela de pago, que no realiza bien la llamada de retorno a la página esperada, y no tiene relación con el código que se está compartiendo en la pregunta.